WebStorm 2024.3 - Dev Server not updating on Edit (AstroJS)
I'm currently working on a site using AstroJS in WebStorm. When I run a dev server npm run dev / npx astro dev, changes I make to page content in files don't update the localhost in my browser (Google Chrome) to reflect those changes on edit.
I've searched everywhere for an answer. I've read about Live Edit but that seems to be for html, css, and js files only. And it seems to only work when you're running a debug session. When I run the dev server in debug mode it doesn't make a difference either. I'm really at a loss because this used to work in VS Code with no issues and I'm trying to make the switch from VS Code to WebStorm.

Apart from IDEs, does the same work in a regular browser in this exact project? It's expected to be the same, the support for hot reload doesn't need the explicit support from IDE

Sorry, I dont get what you mean. Could you clarify what you mean by work in a regular browser in this exact project?

Try to run npm run dev and open localhost in a browser instead of ide. Does it update on changes according to your expectations?

Ah, sorry. I didnt clarify that the localhost was in fact opened in my browser. When i use run dev, i always open the localhost url in my main browser.

If you don't use webstorm's builtin preview, I don't think it's related to it. Hot reload is a common feature, I cannot say how it works in astro, if it doesn't work correctly, this could be specific to your setup. As long as you make changes to files, it's affected by specific dev server you run with "dev" command, not by ide. Make sure you really do them, by pressing ctrl+s or enabling autosave https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/saving-and-reverting-changes.html

Are you on Windows? Perhaps that's why hot reloading is not working (just speculating)

@mb21 I am in fact on windows. I have a buddy who says he's had no issues with it (also using AstroJS). He's on linux

Have a look at https://github.com/withastro/astro/issues/4419, but maybe just use WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)
